# What is a way to smoothly convert a number from $0$ to $100$ to a number from $0$ to $7$, with $1.75$ as the midpoint?

Tags: trigonometry

I am working on a problem for some animation software I am writing. I came up with this function, working backward from a graph:

$0.8733\cdot \arctan \left(x^a\cdot -2.1855\right)+1$

The graph is viewable here:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zdmshghya8

The idea is that from time $0$ to time $1$, graphed on $x$, the value that I'm animating decays to zero, but in a smooth way that is pleasing to the eye, rather than linearly. By changing the value **a**, the smoothness can be biased toward the beginning or the end of the motion. So far so good.

The problem is that from a perceptual point of view, acceptable values for **a** are $0 <$**a**$ <= 7$, but a middle, balanced value for **a** is $1.75$. This is more easily understandable by looking at the graph. You'll notice that for **a**$ = 1.75$, an $x$ of around $0.5$ gives a $y$ of around $0.5$.

I want to present the user with the option to input a value for **a** between $0$ and $100$, and $50$ should map to the middle-looking value of $1.75$. But I am not sure how to do this - I'm sure it's obvious from this post that I am not at all versed in math.

For the moment I am doing this, but I am sure this is a naive way to do it, and will lead to a hiccup for values around $50$ input by the user:

```
if (f >= 0 && f <= 50)
    return (f * 1.75) / 50;
else if (f > 50 && f <=100)
    return 2 * (f/50) * 1.75;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, $1.75/7 = 0.25$, and $50/100 = 0.5$, and $0.5^2 = 0.25$, so you can do something like:

$f(x)= 7*\dfrac {x^2} {100^2}$

It satisfies the following statements:

- $f(0) = 0$
- $f(50) = 1.75$
- $f(100) = 7$

Plot from 0 to 100:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

You can consider an equation like
$$
f(a) = A a^2 + B a + C 
$$
and find the parameters $A$, $B$ and $C$ so that $f(0)=0$, $f(100)=7$ and $f(50)=1.75$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Spline Interpolation*, which yields a continuous 3rd-degree polynomial function.

The function is guaranteed to be twice-differentiable (`f`, `f'` and `f''` are viable functions).

This attribute will effectively give a "smooth appearance" to the original function.

**Here is the function for your specific three points $(0,0),(50,1.75),(100,7)$:**

$
 f(x)=
 \begin{cases}
  0.000007x^3 + 0.0175x                                  & \text{$ 0 \leq x \leq  50$}\\
 -0.000007(x-50)^3 + 0.00105(x-50)^2 + 0.07(x-50) + 1.75 & \text{$50 \leq x \leq 100$}
 \end{cases}
$

[image]

**Here is a piece of C code for any given three points $(x_0,y_0),(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$:**

```
void Spline(double x[3],double y[3], // input
            double A[2],double B[2], // output
            double C[2],double D[2]) // output
{
    double w[2];
    double h[2];
    double ftt[3];

    w[0] = (x[1]-x[0]);
    w[1] = (x[2]-x[1]);

    h[0] = (y[1]-y[0])/w[0];
    h[1] = (y[2]-y[1])/w[1];

    ftt[0] = 0;
    ftt[1] = 3*(h[1]-h[0])/(w[1]+w[0]);
    ftt[2] = 0;

    A[0] = (ftt[1]-ftt[0])/(6*w[0]);
    A[1] = (ftt[2]-ftt[1])/(6*w[1]);

    B[0] = ftt[0]/2;
    B[1] = ftt[1]/2;

    C[0] = h[0]-w[0]*(ftt[1]+2*ftt[0])/6;
    C[1] = h[1]-w[1]*(ftt[2]+2*ftt[1])/6;

    D[0] = y[0];
    D[1] = y[1];

    printf("%f <= x <= %f : f(x) = %f(x-%f)^3 + %f(x-%f)^2 + %f(x-%f) + %f\n"
           ,x[0],x[1],A[0],x[0],B[0],x[0],C[0],x[0],D[0]);

    printf("%f <= x <= %f : f(x) = %f(x-%f)^3 + %f(x-%f)^2 + %f(x-%f) + %f\n"
           ,x[1],x[2],A[1],x[1],B[1],x[1],C[1],x[1],D[1]);
}
```

Please note that the above code assumes $x_0 < x_1 < x_2$.

**Here is a piece of C code for any given number of points $(x_0,y_0),(x_1,y_1),...,(x_N,y_N)$:**

```
void Spline(double x[N+1],double y[N+1], // input
            double A[N],double B[N],     // output
            double C[N],double D[N])     // output
{
    int i;

    double w[N];
    double h[N];
    double ftt[N+1];

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        w[i] = (x[i+1]-x[i]);
        h[i] = (y[i+1]-y[i])/w[i];
    }

    ftt[0] = 0;
    for (i=0; i<N-1; i++)
        ftt[i+1] = 3*(h[i+1]-h[i])/(w[i+1]+w[i]);
    ftt[N] = 0;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        A[i] = (ftt[i+1]-ftt[i])/(6*w[i]);
        B[i] = ftt[i]/2;
        C[i] = h[i]-w[i]*(ftt[i+1]+2*ftt[i])/6;
        D[i] = y[i];
        printf("%f <= x <= %f : f(x) = %f(x-%f)^3 + %f(x-%f)^2 + %f(x-%f) + %f\n"
               ,x[i],x[i+1],A[i],x[i],B[i],x[i],C[i],x[i],D[i]);
    }
}
```

Please note that the above code assumes $x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_N$.

Answer (score 0):

try this one: $y - a = -b \ln (x-c)$ where $a, b, c$ are sliders. I like it at $a = 0.6, b = 1.1, c = -0.7$

Try it!