# Spline interpolation explanation

Tags: interpolation, spline

[image]

I'm trying to learn about spline interpolation, and I'm struggling to understand what h_i^3 is in the second and third equation. I don't understand how they derived that equation.

I'm trying to code that into MATLAB but I don't understand what h3i is

Comment: [My first answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/713284/131263) ever on this website. It doesn't refer exactly to what you're asking, but it might help you understanding a little bit. You can see exactly what $h$ is, if you look in the "code" part.

Comment: @barakmanos I tried looking at your code, but I'm still confused haha. Does h^3_i mean that you cube h_i?

Comment: Yes, here $h_i^3 = h_i\times h_i\times h_i$. You get the second and third equation by expanding $S_i(t_i) = y_i$ and $S_i(t_{i+1}) = y_{i+1}$, as the text says; try expanding them yourself and see what you get.